# Compare date of user's last posts

Tags: posts, users, date, comparison

I want to compare the date of a user's last two posts. I'm new to WordPress developing. I have written this code but I'm not sure if it's correct. Please help me in correcting it:

```
$ID                  = $post->ID;
$user_id             = $post->post_author;
$author_recent_posts = get_most_recent_post_of_user( $user_id );
$last_post_id        = $author_recent_posts[1]->post_id;
$last_post           = get_post($last_post_id);
$last_post_date      = $last_post->post_date;
$post_date           = $post->post_date;

if ( $post_date - $last_post_date > 24*60*60 )
    return;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/), you're manipulating [`get_most_recent_post_of_user()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_most_recent_post_of_user)'s returned value the wrong way. `get_most_recent_post_of_user()` directly returns the `post_date_gmt` among `blog_id`, `post_id`, and `post_gmt_ts`.

Anyway, if you want to get the **2** last posts of a specific **author**, use [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead, which should by default get last posts in the order you need.

```
$author_id = $author_id;

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'author'         => $author_id,
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
);

$query      = new WP_Query( $args );
$last_posts = $query->get_posts(); /*Array of post objects*/
```

Now, you've got only the 2 last [WP_Post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) objects accessible this way:

```
$last_post        = $last_posts[0]; /*The most recent post object*/
$second_last_post = $last_posts[1]; /*The second most recent post object*/
```

If you still need to compare the 2 last post's dates:

```
$last_post_date        = $last_post->post_date_gmt;
$second_last_post_date = $second_last_post->post_date_gmt;
```

Note that we now have 2 **GMT** string dates to deal with. For your comparaison, we'll convert them to [timestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$last_post_date        = strtotime( $last_post_date );
$second_last_post_date = strtotime( $second_last_post_date );

if ( ( $last_post_date - $post_date ) > 86400 )
    return;
```